# How can i use a builtin analyzer in my entity with Hibernate Search

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

i have a custom analyzer but i want to use the built in "WhitespaceAnalyzer"  that Hibernate provides for this spesific field.

My field looks like this:

```
@FullTextField(analyzer = "WhitespaceAnalyzer", projectable = Projectable.YES, termVector = TermVector.NO)
@Column(name = "MY_FIELD")
private String myField;
```

when i use `analyzer = "WhitespaceAnalyzer"` i get an error
`HSEARCH000353: Unknown analyzer: 'WhitespaceAnalyzer'. Make sure you defined this analyzer.`

Do i also have to define the built in analyser in the application.properties?

My main problem is that the field has values that look like this:
`1#J, 2#J, 3#N`
and i want to index the terms separately `1#J` `2#J` etc and i thought i could use the WhitespaceAnalyzer for the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i should have used the name "whitespace" instead of "WhitespaceAnalyzer"

see: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-lucene-analysis